# Apache PHP/PDO - Login timeout expired

Tags: php, apache, pdo, odbc

### PHP statement

```
new PDO($nonLocalhostDsn)
```

### Running from the shell

```
php index.php
```

> Result = Connection OK

### Running from a web browser

```
http://hostname/index.php
```

> Result = Login timeout expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```